# Unable to reproduce results with PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I can't reproduce my results each times. I try to set random seed and only use the one GPU.
My results are different very much, the acc often differs from 1% to 5%, or even 10%. I think there is something wrong with the code, but I don't know. I'm not a professional programmer, so I looked up some posts, but they all said that you just need to set the appropriate random seed. I think I fixed all the seeds on the official website, but the results still cannot be repeated. I don't know where to start to check this code, I hope you can help me.
I am not
my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys, os
from random import shuffle
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from models.gat import GATNet
from models.gat_gcn import GAT_GCN
from models.gcn import GCNNet
from models.ginconv import GINConvNet
from utils import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def set_random_seed(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)

# training function at each epoch
def train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    print('Training on {} samples...'.format(len(train_loader.dataset)))
    model.train()
    total_train = torch.Tensor()
    total_label = torch.Tensor()
    train_losses = []
    for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        data = data.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = loss_fn(output, data.y.view(-1,1).float()).to(device)
        #loss = torch.mean(loss).float()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_losses.append(loss.item())
        if batch_idx % LOG_INTERVAL == 0:
            print('Train epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch,
                                                                           batch_idx * len(data.x),
                                                                           len(train_loader.dataset),
                                                                           100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader),
                                                                           loss.item()))                                                                                                                                    
    total_train = torch.cat((total_train, output.cpu()), 0)
    total_label = torch.cat((total_label, data.y.view(-1, 1).cpu()), 0)
    G_train = total_label.detach().numpy().flatten()
    P_train = total_train.detach().numpy().flatten()
    ret = [auc(G_train,P_train),pre(G_train,P_train),recall(G_train,P_train),f1(G_train,P_train),acc(G_train,P_train),mcc(G_train,P_train),spe(G_train,P_train)]
    print('train_auc',ret[0])
    print('train_pre',ret[1])
    print('train_recall',ret[2])
    print('train_f1',ret[3])
    print('train_acc',ret[4])
    print('train_mcc',ret[5])
    print('train_spe',ret[6])
    print('train_loss',np.average(train_losses))
    return G_train, P_train, np.average(train_losses)

def predicting(model, device, loader):
    model.eval()
    total_preds = torch.Tensor()
    total_labels = torch.Tensor()
    print('Make prediction for {} samples...'.format(len(loader.dataset)))
    losses = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in loader:
            data = data.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            loss = loss_fn(output, data.y.view(-1,1).float())
            #loss = torch.mean(loss).float().to(device)
            losses.append(loss.item())
            total_preds = torch.cat((total_preds, output.cpu()), 0)
            total_labels = torch.cat((total_labels, data.y.view(-1, 1).cpu()), 0)
    return total_labels.numpy().flatten(),total_preds.numpy().flatten(),np.average(losses)


datasets = [['cyp'][int(sys.argv[1])]] 
modeling = [GINConvNet, GATNet, GAT_GCN, GCNNet][int(sys.argv[2])]
model_st = modeling.__name__

cuda_name = "cuda:0"
if len(sys.argv)>3:
    cuda_name = ["cuda:0","cuda:1"][int(sys.argv[3])]
print('cuda_name:', cuda_name)
    
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 512
TEST_BATCH_SIZE = 512
LR = 0.0005
LOG_INTERVAL = 20
NUM_EPOCHS = 1000

print('Learning rate: ', LR)
print('Epochs: ', NUM_EPOCHS)


# 
set_random_seed(8)

# Main program: iterate over different datasets
for dataset in datasets:
    print('\nrunning on ', model_st + '_' + dataset )
    processed_data_file_train = 'data/processed/' + dataset + '_train.pt'
    processed_data_file_test = 'data/processed/' + dataset + '_test.pt'
    processed_data_file_valid = 'data/processed/' + dataset + '_valid.pt'
    if ((not os.path.isfile(processed_data_file_train)) or (not os.path.isfile(processed_data_file_test))):
        print('please run create_data.py to prepare data in pytorch format!')
    else:
        train_data = TestbedDataset(root='data', dataset=dataset+'_train')
        test_data = TestbedDataset(root='data', dataset=dataset+'_test')
        valid_data = TestbedDataset(root='data', dataset=dataset+'_valid')
        train_set = pd.read_csv('try/cyp_train.csv')
        
        
        #train_size = int(0.8 * len(train_data))
        #valid_size = len(train_data) - train_size
        #train_data, valid_data = torch.utils.data.random_split(train_data, [train_size, valid_size])        
        
        
        # make data PyTorch mini-batch processing ready
        train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
        valid_loader = DataLoader(valid_data, batch_size=TEST_BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)
        test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=TEST_BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)
        #pos_weight_np = pos_weight(train_set)
        # training the model
        device = torch.device(cuda_name if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        model = modeling().to(device)
        loss_fn = nn.BCELoss()
        #loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(reduction='none', pos_weight=pos_weight_np.to(device))
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LR)
        best_loss = 100
        best_test_auc = 1000
        best_test_ci = 0
        best_epoch = -1
        patience = 20
        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=patience, verbose=True)
        model_file_name = 'model_' + model_st + '_' + dataset +  '.model'
        result_file_name = 'result_' + model_st + '_' + dataset +  '.csv'
        train_losses=[]
        train_accs=[]
        valid_losses=[]
        valid_accs=[]
        for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
            G_T,P_T,train_loss = train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch+1)
            print('predicting for valid data')
            G,P,loss_valid = predicting(model, device, valid_loader)
            loss_valid_value = loss_valid
            print('valid_loss',loss_valid)
            print('valid_auc',auc(G,P))
            print('valid_pre',pre(G,P))
            print('valid_recall',recall(G,P))
            print('valid_f1',f1(G,P))
            print('valid_acc',acc(G,P))
            print('valid_mcc',mcc(G,P))
            print('valid_spe',spe(G,P))
            train_losses.append(np.array(train_loss))
            valid_losses.append(loss_valid)
            train_accs.append(acc(G_T,P_T))
            valid_accs.append(acc(G,P))
            b = pd.DataFrame({'value':G,'prediction':P})
            names = 'model_'+'value_validation'+'.csv'
            b.to_csv(names,sep=',') 
            early_stopping(loss_valid, model)      
            if early_stopping.early_stop:                
                print("Early stopping")              
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_file_name)
                print('predicting for test data')
                G,P,loss_test = predicting(model, device, test_loader)
                ret = [auc(G,P),pre(G,P),recall(G,P),f1(G,P),acc(G,P),mcc(G,P),spe(G,P)]
                with open(result_file_name,'w') as f:
                    f.write(','.join(map(str,ret)))
                best_test_loss = loss_test
                print('auc improved at epoch ',best_epoch,'auc',ret[0],'pre',ret[1],'recall',ret[2],'f1',ret[3],'acc',ret[4],'mcc',ret[5],'spe',ret[6])
                a = pd.DataFrame({'value':G,'prediction':P})
                name = 'model_'+'value_test'+'.csv'
                a.to_csv(name,sep=',')
                break
            else:
                print('no early stopping')
        df = pd.DataFrame({'train_loss':train_losses,'valid_loss':valid_losses,'train_accs':train_accs,'valid_accs':valid_accs})
        names = 'model_'+'loss_acc'+'.csv'
        df.to_csv(names,sep=',')
```

Comment: Try torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True) and see if you get an error. Also read about deterministic behaviour and dataloaders: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html (final part).

Comment: I tried, and it did get an error. I figured that even if PyTorch couldn't repeat the result  
 completely, it may wouldn't be too different like my result.